# What is the reason for Hibernate Error, SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, heroku

I merely try to post and get the data from the application being hosted in Heroku. But I get this Error,

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu May 21 11:27:53 UTC 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I tested this on my localhost with link  Heroku Postgresql database and doesn't appeared any error and committed in success both post and get. The above-mentioned error is only occurring when tried to fetch or post data through the Heroku address.

Following is the code segments,

Entity class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "notes")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
public class Note {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    @NotBlank
    private String content;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

}
```

Controller class

```
import com.mcq.webapp.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.mcq.webapp.model.Note;
import com.mcq.webapp.repository.NoteRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NoteController {

    @Autowired
    NoteRepository noteRepository;

    @GetMapping("/notes")
    public List<Note> getAllNotes() {
        return noteRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/notes")
    public Note createNote(@Valid @RequestBody Note note) {
        return noteRepository.save(note);
    }

    @GetMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public Note getNoteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteId) {
        return noteRepository.findById(noteId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteId));
    }

    @PutMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public Note updateNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteId,
                                           @Valid @RequestBody Note noteDetails) {

        Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteId));

        note.setTitle(noteDetails.getTitle());
        note.setContent(noteDetails.getContent());

        Note updatedNote = noteRepository.save(note);
        return updatedNote;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/notes/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long noteId) {
        Note note = noteRepository.findById(noteId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Note", "id", noteId));

        noteRepository.delete(note);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
import com.mcq.webapp.model.Note;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;



@Repository
public interface NoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Note, Long> {

}
```

In this case the same Project the same database but only different is the environment. Therefore What is the reason for that. The Program is working in localhost but not working in the Heroku environment.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your hosted DB is correctly configured? Tables already created and everything? Check also your app.properties, especially ddl-auto.

Comment: @Maaaatt thanks for the comment. yes I have added as follows,   SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO = update

Comment: If the schema is not already created I believe it (ddl-auto:update) won't create it for you. might be worth connecting via a client and check what is on your db.

Comment: Thank you @ Maaaatt , I solved my problem. I updated as this spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem according to @Maaaatt comments. I updated the application.properties file as follows,

```
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

Thanks, :D.

Comment: You're welcome :)
This is good for test environment but it's in general advised to not be used otherwise.
You should script your schema creation rather than relying on your java model and the jpa ddl-auto:create or use dedicated tools to migrate your db.